# Should I bring a copy of an article I wrote in a science journal to my interview?

Tags: interview, medicine

I'm currently applying to a combined pre-med/medical program. This program guarantees a spot in the school system's medical school (assuming a certain GPA is maintained etc.). I'm between high school and undergrad, taking a few years off for intensive Judaic studies.

In 11th grade, I submitted an essay to a medical journal's contest for high school juniors and seniors. My essay (though not first place) was accepted for publication, and was published in that journal. The essay was basically a review paper of research done about a specific treatment (not CPAP) for obstructive sleep apnea.

**Should I bring a copy of my essay with me to the interview at the medical school?** (*Does it matter that I don't believe the essay was particularly well-written?*)

- Is there anything to gain? (*I know how to write a paper for a journal*)
- Is there anything to lose? (*Might this appear presumptuous or arrogant? The paper doesn't actually look that good, at least to me*)

Comment: Did you mention this paper in the application package for the medical program?

Comment: @scaaahu Yes, I did.

Comment: @scaaahu http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/50027/should-i-bring-a-copy-of-an-article-i-wrote-in-a-science-journal-to-my-interview#comment116748_50028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should.

I expect that a common question in any interview would be to ask the candidate about any piece of work of which the candidate feels particularly proud or pleased. Being able to refer to your publication -- and have a copy of it with you -- would be a positive thing.

Regarding your opinion of the work -- you might be your own worst critic. Clearly the journal editor felt it was acceptable for publication. In a positive spin, you could outline in your interview where you feel the work could have been improved, showing a capacity for reflective practice.

Comment: I ended up taking the essay with me. I had forgotten that I had included a pdf of the article with my emailed application. The interviewer had read it before the interview, and repeatedly told me that she was very impressed with it :)

Answer (score 1):

It makes no harm to bring anything to the job interview. Depending on the situation you may decide just not to show it.

Among various diplomas, certificates and the like, a good looking copy of your best article (or two) should have an important place in your portfolio.